# Storing PDF files in mysql and access with MS Access front end

Tags: mysql, ms-access, pdf

Need some guidance on this.

Front-end is MS Access 2010.  Back-end is MySQL.  We have small customer database that is used in various offices around our area.  Staff connects through MYODB from the office, from home, from their car, etc.

Our issue is, would there be away to store a pdf file or 2 within our mysql database, so that staff can access said file from anywhere through the MS Access front-end?

I know we can simply store the file on the file system, and reference the url in a simple text field, but by doing so, the data is in the public_html directory, which makes it available to anyone.

Also, ideally, we would want to have a simple upload method so that a few staff members can upload the pdf file into mysql.

Any suggestions would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: stop thinking "pdf" and start thinking "blob". Mysql couldn't care less what's in a blob field. it's just a chunk of bytes that's stored/retrieved as needed.

Comment: Thanks.  But still having trouble tieing everything together.  I can create a blob field, but how to get Access to upload the file to that field and make it accessible to staff.

Comment: As said by Marc, you can store blob in Mysql, sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3375421/3142139

Comment: I'm getting somewhere, just not sure what I'm doing.  Through myphp admin I created a blob field in an existing table.  Then, in access I updated the link and access sees the field an an OLE object.  When you click on the particular field withn the table, it says it's empty.  Right click to upload.  So I uploaded a small PDF as  test.  It uploaded the file, but somehow it converted it to a .bin file, and it's no longer functional.

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting this organized.  Any help is greatly appreciated